# QUERY IS NOT RETURNING PREDEFINED VALUE FOR WHEN THERE IS NOTHING

Tags: database, postgresql

I want to query zero returns for null or nonexistent values, in the examples below, see what was the purpose and what was the output I received

```
SELECT
    count(case when coalesce("CUSTOMER",'') = '' then 1 else 0 end) AS "OFFLINE GENERAL"
FROM
    tbl_status
WHERE
    "AVAILABLE" = '*OFFLINE'
    AND "CUSTOMER" IN (
        'CLIENT1',
        'CLIENT2',
        'CLIENT3',
        'CLIENT4',
        'CLIENT5'
    )
GROUP BY
    "CUSTOMER"
```

**RETURNED**

```
------
1 | 1
------
2 | 1
------
```

**GOAL**

```
1 | 1
-----
2 | 1
-----
3 | 0
-----
4 | 0
-----
5 | 0
...
```

Comment: You have a where condition in your query, you will only have result where "CUSTOMER" is 'CLIENT1','CLIENT2','CLIENT3', 'CLIENT4','CLIENT5'. No null value no empty string. ADD a condtion like `("CUSTOMER"  in ( 'CLIENT1','CLIENT2','CLIENT3', 'CLIENT4','CLIENT5') or "CUSTOMER"  is null)`

Comment: can you please show an example, do not understand very well?

Comment: Unrelated, but your count statement is the same as `count(*)`.  There's no difference between counting 1's or counting 0's.  The only time count doesn't count something is when it's null and you've ensured that it it will never be null.

Comment: @Arun SELECT
    count(case when coalesce("CUSTOMER",'') = '' then 1 else 0 end) AS "OFFLINE GENERAL"
FROM
    tbl_status
WHERE
    "AVAILABLE" = '*OFFLINE'
    AND ("CUSTOMER" in ( 'CLIENT1','CLIENT2','CLIENT3', 'CLIENT4','CLIENT5') or "CUSTOMER" is null)
GROUP BY
    "CUSTOMER"

Comment: The above query returned nothing

Comment: @Jeremy Shouldn't use if?

Comment: `SELECT case when "CUSTOMER" is not null then 1 else 0 end AS "OFFLINE GENERAL" FROM tbl_status WHERE "AVAILABLE" = '*OFFLINE' AND ("CUSTOMER" in ( 'CLIENT1','CLIENT2','CLIENT3', 'CLIENT4','CLIENT5') or "CUSTOMER" is null) GROUP BY "CUSTOMER"`

Comment: It returned 1 for all non-null values, but nulls are not yet

Comment: If you could edit your question to show some example data and the expected results from those data, it would be easier to assist you.  I'm not sure what you mean by `Shouldn't use if?`

Comment: Sorry, it was not clear, and I already solved the problem, thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a CTE with an outer join:

```
WITH cust AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM (VALUES
          ('CLIENT1'),
          ('CLIENT2'),
          ('CLIENT3'),
          ('CLIENT4'),
          ('CLIENT5')) AS cust(c)
)
SELECT cust.c,
    count(*)
       FILTER (WHERE coalesce("CUSTOMER",'') = '')
       AS "OFFLINE GENERAL"
FROM tbl_status
   RIGHT JOIN cust
      ON cust.c = tbl_status."CUSTOMER"
WHERE
    "AVAILABLE" = '*OFFLINE'
GROUP BY cust.c;
```